# How to get dynamic Schema and Logical names for @odata.bind in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm trying to clone entity record in Dynamics CRM 2016 using Javascript and CRM Web API.

But I had problems when I tried to code dynamic binding of lookup fields.

In my code I have several methods:

1. Retrieving record -> returns JSON object with lookup fields like "_createdby_value"
2. Creating record -> takes JSON object, deletes it's uniqueidentifier and create new record using CRM Web API.

So, I want to copy all lookup field from parent record, but I can't find a way how to retrieve values for @odata.bind for each lookup field.

I found method:

```
/api/data/v8.1/$metadata#opportunities/$entity
```

It returns the whole system metadata information, but I need only one EntitySet with it's NavigatonPropertyBindings

They look like:

```
<EntitySet Name="opportunities" EntityType="Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.opportunity">
    <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="opportunitycompetitors_association" Target="competitors"/>
    <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="campaignid" Target="campaigns"/>
    <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="parentcontactid" Target="contacts"/>
    <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Opportunity_Phonecalls" Target="phonecalls"/>
    <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Opportunity_AsyncOperations" Target="asyncoperations"/>
```

So my solution is to retrieve this data and generate `@odata.bind` based on this EntitySet object.

Help me please to retrieve it, or maybe you have another way to clone entity record?